# Execute Cloud9 compiled C++ code on Windows

Tags: windows, compile, c++, aws-cloud9

I am currently using C++ in my Cloud9 (c9.io) workspace. I have created a program in Cloud9 that I would to distribute to a few other people. They are running Windows. How would I compile my C++ code within Cloud9 to be usable on Windows? I tried downloading the compiled code that I had onto my Windows computer, but could not figure out how to run it. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C9 runs on Ubuntu Linux and uses the gcc compiler to create binaries for Linux.

You would need a cross compiler for windows to build executable for that OS. Probably more trouble than it is worth.

Alternatively, you could install gcc on your windows PC and compile there under Cygwin or Mingw